# FabricJS Error in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor, fabricjs

Hey I have a react projekt where I am using FabricJS. 
For ~2-3 weeks i am getting the following error:
"FabricCan.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: _fabric2.default.Canvas is not a constructor"

But the following code worked fine a few weeks ago.

```
import React from 'react';
import fabric from 'fabric';
```

...

```
render: function(){
   var can = new fabric.Canvas("test");

   return(
     <canvas id="test"> </canvas>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue.

Use

```
import 'fabric';
```

instead of

```
import fabric from 'fabric';
```

It allows fabric variable to be defined globally.

Or you can use

```
import { fabric } from 'fabric';
```

Answer (score 0):

you should move the call to create the fabric canvas out of the `render` function. the element does not exist on the page yet. [Instead you should do it on the `componentDidMount` call like in this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/STHayden/uaucbkqz/).

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer, but I still get the error.

Comment: you should post code working in a snippet demonstrating your bug or we will just be taking random guesses at the solution.

Comment: import React from 'react';
import fabric from 'fabric';

var FabricCanvas = React.createClass({

  componentDidMount: function(){
    var can = new fabric.Canvas("test");
  },

  render: function(){
    return <canvas id="test"> </canvas>;
  }
});

module.exports = FabricCanvas;

Comment: seems like the same thing that is in this jsfiddle I made: https://jsfiddle.net/STHayden/uaucbkqz/

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why but the following works for me:

1. npm uninstall fabric --save
2. npm install react-webpack

then import the following:

"import {fabric} from 'fabric-webpack';